# Radio buttons in AlertDialog don't change when touched

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

This is more of a UX issue than a real problem but it would be nice if I can fix it.

I'm creating a single choice `AlertDialog` similar to the image...

[image]

The code I use to create it is...

```
private void createGuideViewChooserDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select Guide View");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(guideViewChooserDialogItems, currentGuideView, this);
    guideViewChooserDialog = builder.create();
    guideViewChooserDialog.show();
}
```

...so basically I use an `int` called `currentGuideView` to set which radio-button is shown as selected and my `Activity` implements `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` hence using `this` in the call to `setSingleChoiceItems(...)`.

The `onClick(...)` listener does some simple things based on the item selected then calls `guideViewChooserDialog.cancel()`.

The problem I'm having is when I touch one of the list items, the item is briefly highlighted to acknowledge the touch BUT the `AlertDialog` disappears without showing a change of selected radio-button.

Everything works fine and my `onClick(...)` listener gets which item was touched but it's just a bit disconcerting that the dialog disappears without seeing the radio-button selection change.

I'm testing this on an HTC Desire w/ Android v2.2. Is this planned behaviour or a bug in either v2.2 or the HTC implementation of it? Is there anything I can (or should) do so the selected item's radio-button is correctly shown as selected before the dialog disappears?

Comment: Could you please paste the full code. Hard to figure it out when we have to guess as to what those variables refer to...

Comment: Which variables are you having to guess about? `guideViewChooserDialogItems` is a `CharSequence[]` for the text and as I mentioned in the question, `currentGuideView` is an `int` (between 0-2) to set which radio-button to select when the `AlertDialog` is first shown. The point is it works but when I touch an item the `AlertDialog` doesn't automatically switch radio-button selection. I need to know if I have to manualy switch it myself (can't find a method to do this) or if `AlertDialog` should do it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog is getting dimissed immediately because that's what you must have set it to do in your `DialogInterface.CnClickListener`. If you don't want it to be dimissed, then add a button for the user to click "ok", confirming their radio choice and then dismiss the dialog.

Comment: It's not how I wanted to do it but this is the closest I can get to smoothing out the problem. I added OK/Cancel buttons and it's now behaving better from a UX perspective. Thanks.